# C# Multiplication Table logic

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

I'm making a c# program that shows the multiplication table, by using my code I can print only complete table, how can I print random table as below.

my code bit:

```
using System;  
public class Exer
{  
    public static void Main() 
{
   int j,n;
   
    Console.Write("\n\n");
    Console.Write("Display the multiplication table:\n");
    Console.Write("-----------------------------------");
    Console.Write("\n\n");   

   Console.Write("Input the number (Table to be calculated) : ");
   n= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());   
   Console.Write("\n");
   for(j=1;j<=10;j++)
   {
     Console.Write("{0} X {1} = {2} \n",n,j,n*j);
   }
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
1 x 2 = 2
2 x 2 = 4
3 x 2 = 6
1 x 4 = 4
2 x 4 = 8
3 x 4 = 12
1 x 6 = 6
2 x 6 = 12
3 x 6 = 18
1 x 8 = 8
2 x 8 = 16
3 x 8 = 24
1 x 10 = 10
2 x 10 = 20
3 x 10 = 30
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables in your picture are NOT random, though. There is a definite pattern. The function, `DisplayMath()`, is receiving an integer parameter; 3, 4, and 5 in the picture.

The output in the pictures is most likely produced by two NESTED `for` loops.

The integer parameter is controlling the INNER for loop, which goes from 1 to the parameter, incrementing by 1.

The OUTER loop goes from 2 to 10, incrementing by 2.

Possible code:

```
public static void Main() {
    DisplayMath(4);
}

public static void DisplayMath(int x) {
    for(int y=2; y<=10; y=y+2) {
        for(int z=1; z<=x; z++) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} X {1} = {2}",z,y,z*y);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 X 2 = 2
2 X 2 = 4
3 X 2 = 6
4 X 2 = 8
1 X 4 = 4
2 X 4 = 8
3 X 4 = 12
4 X 4 = 16
1 X 6 = 6
2 X 6 = 12
3 X 6 = 18
4 X 6 = 24
1 X 8 = 8
2 X 8 = 16
3 X 8 = 24
4 X 8 = 32
1 X 10 = 10
2 X 10 = 20
3 X 10 = 30
4 X 10 = 40
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the required output, you need to change the for loop logic a little.
Because there is a logic in the expected result that you need to get before start coding, that isn't a *'random'* table

```
for(j=2; j<=10; j=j+2 )
{
   for (mathNumber = 1; mathNumber <= n; mathNumber++  )       
   {
        Console.Write("{0} X {1} = {2} \n",mathNumber,j,mathNumber*j);
   }
}
```

As you can see the result must be the result of the n first numbers (being n the parameter you get from Console, but perhaps is better that you get it as argument) multiplyed by the numbers 2,4,6,8,10